# HTTP request Timed out

Tags: excel, vba, winhttprequest, request-timed-out

I'm trying to check a webpage if it is logged in or not. For that I used win http GET request for google to test it. But i'm getting

> "The Operation  Timed Out" Error

after Send command.

Also Tried with xmlHTTP and serverxmlHTTP.

```
Dim xmlHTTP As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim url As String


url = "https://www.google.com/"

'
'Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

xmlHTTP.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000


xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
'xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHTTP.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText
```

"The Operation  Timed Out" Error after Send command.

Comment: `html.body.innerHTML = xThemlHTTP.responseText` can not work if you are not defining `"xThemlHTTP"`. Maybe `html.body.innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText`?

Comment: Sorry that waws typo error when posting on here. I have edited the info.

Comment: I have tried your code as it is and it is working. Could you show your error?

Comment: Same here, with the exception of using `Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` instead of `Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`, as the latter doesn't support `.SetTimeouts`. Works with both WinHTTP and MSXML2. So I suspect some kind of interference (Firewall / AV software) at your end. No timeout error here.